# Better way to operate on a value in a column based on the value in another column of that row?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a simple data frame composed of Year, Month, and a measured value. I wanted to create a "Normalized" column that is equal to dividing that timestamps value by the average value of all measurements belonging to that same month. I ended up with this loop, but I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do it with something from the tidyverse

```
for (i in 1:nrow(my_data)){
  my_data[i,"Normalized"] <- my_data[i, "MERRA2"]/ mean_monthly[[my_data[i,"Month"]]]
}
```

where mean_monthly is

```
mean_monthly <- apply(merra2_data[,2:13], 2, mean, na.rm=T)
```

head of the dataframe

```
  Year Month   MERRA2 Normalized
1 2000     1 7.217474  1.0267520
2 2000     2 7.700417  1.0625818
3 2000     3 8.004980  1.0532328
4 2000     4 7.994653  0.9930986
5 2000     5 8.317802  1.1213321
6 2000     6 6.734449  0.9501416
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **dplyr**.
I created a sample dataset and calculated the required output by using **dplyr** library

```
df <- data.frame(Year = rep(2000:2004, each=60),
                 Month= rep(1:12, 5, each=5),
                 MERRA2= 1:300)
df1 <- df %>% group_by(Year, Month) %>% mutate(Normalised = MERRA2/mean(MERRA2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

my_data <- my_data %>%
  group_by(Year, Month) %>%
  mutate(Normalized = MERRA2/mean(MERRA2))
```